# how to create a UDP server that will listen on multiple ports in python?

Tags: python, udp

this is my server:

```
import socket

for port in range(33,128):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
    while True:
        (client_name, client_adress) = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        print chr(port)
    server_socket.close()
```

this is my client:

```
import socket


message = raw_input("Enter a message: ")

for letter in message:
    my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    while True:
        my_socket.sendto("", ('127.0.0.1', ord(letter)))
        (data, remote_adress) = my_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    my_socket.close()

print 'The server sent: ' + data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very good in python, but I think you should save your sockets to list inside `for` and then use `select` function in infinite loop outside `for`

```
import socket
import select

sockets = []

for port in range(33,128):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
    sockets.append(server_socket)

empty = []
while True:
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(sockets, empty, empty)
    for s in readable:
         (client_data, client_address) = s.recvfrom(1024)
         print client_address, client_data
for s in sockets:
   s.close()
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it printing to me the port 127 and never stops

Comment: Your example also printing port number. What do you want it print?

Comment: In my example, it prints the letters I sent (it converts the port to letter with ASCII). My purpose was to send an empty message to the port with the number of the ASCII code of the letter I entered, and the server will print me this letters. But in my example it works only if I send the sign '!', because it's ASCII code is 33 (the first port in range).

Comment: Still don't work, now it printing some strange ports that aren't in the range that was written.

Comment: It works. That ports is clients ports, not servers. You should read more about ip and udp.